# run time error show no such table

Tags: android

I am creating three tables in database .Two of the tables are created successfully but third table isn't created.It shows error **as no such table**

**the database class is....**

```
package com.example.mytryapp;

import com.example.mytryapp.model.PendingDues;
import com.example.mytryapp.model.Student;
import com.example.mytryapp.model.Teacher;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "behere.db";

    //table_teacher
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_TEACHER = "teacher_table";
    //TEACHER_TABLE_COLUMNS
    private static final String TEACHER_NAME = "teacher_name";
    private static final String TEACH_FATHER_NAME = "father_name";
    private static final String TEACH_MOTHER_NAME = "mother_name";
    private static final String TEACH_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TEACH_CONTACT = "contact";
    private static final String TEACH_E_MAIL = "e_mail";
    private static final String TEACH_BRANCH = "branch";
    private static final String TEACH_EMP_ID = "_emp_id";

    //STUDENT_TABLE
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_STUDENT="student_table";
    //STUDENT_TABLE_COLUMNS
    private static final String ROLL_NO = "_roll_no";
    private static final String STUDENT_NAME = "student_name";
    private static final String STUDENT_FATHER_NAME = "student_father_name";
    private static final String STUDENT_MOTHER_NAME = "student_mother_name";
    private static final String STUDENT_ADDRESS = "student_address";
    private static final String STUDENT_CONTACT = "student_contact";
    private static final String STUDENT_E_MAIL = "student_e_mail";
    private static final String STUDENT_BRANCH_BATCH = "student_branch_batch";

    //pending_dues_teacher
        private static final String TABLE_NAME_DUES = "pending_dues_table";
        //DUES_TABLE_COLUMNS
        private static final String PENDING_DUES_NOTICE = "pending_dues_notice";
        private static final String PENDING_DUES_ROLLNO = "pending_dues_rollno";
        private static final String PENDING_DUES_ID = "_pending_dues_id";



    SQLiteDatabase data=this.getWritableDatabase();

    Context ctx;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ctx=context;
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "DATABASE CREATED");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            // Create table teacher
            String create_table_teacher = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_TEACHER + " ("
            + TEACH_EMP_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + TEACHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + TEACH_FATHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + TEACH_MOTHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + TEACH_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
            + TEACH_CONTACT + " TEXT,"
            + TEACH_E_MAIL + " TEXT,"
            + TEACH_BRANCH + " TEXT"
            + ");";

            db.execSQL(create_table_teacher);

            // Create table STUDENT
            String CREATE_TABLE_student = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_STUDENT + " ("
                    + ROLL_NO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + STUDENT_FATHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + STUDENT_MOTHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + STUDENT_BRANCH_BATCH + " TEXT,"
                    + STUDENT_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                    + STUDENT_CONTACT + " TEXT,"
                    + STUDENT_E_MAIL + " TEXT"
                    + ");";

              db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_student);       

           // Create table pending dues
                String create_table_pending_dues = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_DUES + " ("
                + PENDING_DUES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + PENDING_DUES_ROLLNO + " TEXT,"
                + PENDING_DUES_NOTICE + " TEXT"
                + ");";

                db.execSQL(create_table_pending_dues);

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHandler Oncreate SQLException",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(se));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHandler Oncreate Exception",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
          Log.d("database operation", "table created"); 
    }


     public void open() throws SQLException
     {
         DatabaseHelper db1 = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
            data = db1.getWritableDatabase();
     }

     public void close()
     {
         data.close();
     }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            // Drop table TEACHER
                        String placeTableDropQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_TEACHER;
                        db.execSQL(placeTableDropQuery);
                        // Drop table STUDENT
                        String ReminderTableDropQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_STUDENT;
                        db.execSQL(ReminderTableDropQuery);
                        // Drop table PENDING DUES
                        String pendingduesTableDropQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_DUES;
                        db.execSQL(pendingduesTableDropQuery);
                        // Upgrade database
                        onCreate(db);

                    } catch (SQLException se) {
                        Log.v("DatabaseHandler onUpgrade SQLException",
                                Log.getStackTraceString(se));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.v("DatabaseHandler onUpgrade Exception",
                                Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
    }

    //add details of teacher
    public String addTeacherData(Teacher teach) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(TEACHER_NAME, teach.getTeacherName());
            values.put(TEACH_FATHER_NAME,teach.getTeacherFatherName());
            values.put(TEACH_MOTHER_NAME,teach.getTeacherMotherName());
            values.put(TEACH_ADDRESS,teach.getTeacherAddress());
            values.put(TEACH_CONTACT,teach.getTeacherContact());
            values.put(TEACH_E_MAIL,teach.getTeacherEmail());
            values.put(TEACH_BRANCH,teach.getTeacherBranch());

            db.insert(TABLE_NAME_TEACHER, null, values);
            db.close();
            return "Record insert succussfully...";
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHelper insertTeacherRecord Exception",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(se));
            return se.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHelper insertTeacherRecord Exception",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return e.getMessage();
        } finally{
            db.close();
        } 
        }
    //get teacher id in edit text
    public Teacher findTeacherID(String teacher_id) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_TEACHER + " WHERE " + TEACHER_NAME + " =  \"" + teacher_id + "\"";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Teacher product = new Teacher();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            product.setTeacherId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            product = null;
        }
            db.close();
        return product;
    }   
    //get teacher login id
    public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseHelper dop)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ=dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] coloumns={TEACH_EMP_ID};
        Cursor CR=SQ.query(TABLE_NAME_TEACHER, coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        return CR;      
    }
    //get student login id
    public Cursor getStudentInformation(DatabaseHelper dop)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ=dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] coloumns={ROLL_NO};
        Cursor CR=SQ.query(TABLE_NAME_STUDENT, coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        return CR;      
    }
    //add student details
    public String addStudentData(Student student) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(STUDENT_NAME, student.getStudentName());
            values.put(STUDENT_FATHER_NAME,student.getStudentFatherName());
            values.put(STUDENT_MOTHER_NAME,student.getStudentMotherName());
            values.put(STUDENT_BRANCH_BATCH,student.getStudentBranch());
            values.put(STUDENT_ADDRESS,student.getStudentAddress());
            values.put(STUDENT_CONTACT,student.getStudentContact());
            values.put(STUDENT_E_MAIL,student.getStudentEmail());

            db.insert(TABLE_NAME_STUDENT, null, values);
            db.close();
            return "Record insert succussfully...";
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHelper insertTeacherRecord Exception",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(se));
            return se.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHelper insertTeacherRecord Exception",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return e.getMessage();
        } finally{
            db.close();
        }        
}   
    //get student id in edit text
    public Student findStudentID(String student_id) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_STUDENT + " WHERE " + STUDENT_NAME + " =  \"" + student_id + "\"";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        Student student = new Student();        
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            student.setStudentId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            student = null;
        }
            db.close();
        return student;
    }   
    public Cursor getRollNo(DatabaseHelper dop)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sq=dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] coloumns={ROLL_NO};
        Cursor cr=sq.query(TABLE_NAME_STUDENT, coloumns, null, null,null,null,null);
        if (cr != null) {
            cr.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cr;
    }   
    public Student findStudentDetail(int student_id) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_STUDENT + " WHERE " + ROLL_NO + " =  \"" + student_id + "\"";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Student product = new Student();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            product.setStudentId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            product.setStudentName(cursor.getString(1));
            product.setStudentFtherName(cursor.getString(2));
            product.setStudentMotherName(cursor.getString(3));
            product.setStudentBranch(cursor.getString(4));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            product = null;
        }
            db.close();
        return product;
    }   
    //add details of teacher
        public String addDuesData(PendingDues dues) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            try {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(PENDING_DUES_ROLLNO, dues.getDueNoticeRollNo());
                values.put(PENDING_DUES_NOTICE,dues.getDueNoticeName());
                db.insert(TABLE_NAME_DUES, null, values);
                db.close();
                return "Record insert succussfully...";
            } catch (SQLiteException se) {
                Log.v("DatabaseHelper insertTeacherRecord Exception",
                        Log.getStackTraceString(se));
                return se.getMessage();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("DatabaseHelper insertTeacherRecord Exception",
                        Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                return e.getMessage();
            } finally{
                db.close();
            } 
            }

}
```

**activity is....**

```
package com.example.mytryapp;

import com.example.mytryapp.model.PendingDues;
import com.example.mytryapp.model.Student;
import com.example.mytryapp.model.Teacher;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ManagePendingDue extends Activity{

    TextView TXT1,TXT2,TXT3,TXT4,TXT5;
    String rollno, due_notice,i;
    EditText DUE_NOTICE,GET_ROLLNO_DUES;
    Button send;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
Context ctxx=this;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar ab=getActionBar();
         ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        setContentView(com.example.mytryapp.R.layout.manage_pending_dues);
        DatabaseHelper DB =new DatabaseHelper(ManagePendingDue.this);
        TXT1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_rollno);
        TXT2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        TXT3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_father);
        TXT4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_mother);
        TXT5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_branch);
        DUE_NOTICE=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_due_notice);
        GET_ROLLNO_DUES=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_rollno_enter); 
        send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send);

        ManageDues m=new ManageDues();

        Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    i = b.getString("userdata");
    int ii=Integer.parseInt(i);

        Student stud = DB.findStudentDetail(ii);
           if (stud != null) {
               TXT1.setText(String.valueOf(stud.getStudentId()));
               TXT2.setText(String.valueOf(stud.getStudentName()));
               TXT3.setText(String.valueOf(stud.getStudentFatherName()));
               TXT4.setText(String.valueOf(stud.getStudentMotherName()));
               TXT5.setText(String.valueOf(stud.getStudentBranch()));        
           }     
           send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GET_ROLLNO_DUES.setText(i);
                due_notice=DUE_NOTICE.getText().toString();

                DatabaseHelper DB=new DatabaseHelper(ctxx);
                DB.open();
                PendingDues dues=new PendingDues(i,due_notice);
                DB.addDuesData(dues);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "insertion sucessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
            }
        });
}     
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater1 = getMenuInflater();
        inflater1.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
                 builder.setMessage("Do you want to logout ?")  
                 .setCancelable(false)  
                 .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  

                         Intent std_time=new Intent(ManagePendingDue.this,ChoosePanel.class);
                        startActivity(new Intent(ManagePendingDue.this,ChoosePanel.class));
                     }  
                 })  
                 .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
                     //  Action for 'NO' Button  
                     dialog.cancel();  
                  }  
                 });  

             //Creating dialog box  
             AlertDialog alert = builder.create();  
             //Setting the title manually  
             alert.setTitle("LOGOUT");  
             alert.show();
                return true;

            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
                this.finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
}
```

**and error in logcat is...**

```
05-20 05:14:54.094: E/SQLiteLog(820): (1) no such table: pending_dues_table
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820): Error inserting pending_dues_rollno=1 pending_dues_notice=pending fees 2500rs
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: pending_dues_table (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO pending_dues_table(pending_dues_rollno,pending_dues_notice) VALUES (?,?)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at com.example.mytryapp.DatabaseHelper.addDuesData(DatabaseHelper.java:290)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at com.example.mytryapp.ManagePendingDue$1.onClick(ManagePendingDue.java:79)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-20 05:14:54.244: E/SQLiteDatabase(820):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 05:14:54.294: I/Choreographer(820): Skipped 114 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: where are you inserting data to `pending_dues_table` tables? YOu are getting this error when you are trying to insert data as the error states

Comment: in ManagePendingDue activity i am insert the data..... on send button click listener

Answer (score 1):

Update the database version to `2`. Note that you will lose all data in your tables when doing that the first time, because you're dropping the tables in `onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion)`.

`private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;`

**Edit:**
Every time you want to change the structure of your tables, `onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion)` needs to be called. And for it to be called, you need to update the database version.

**Edit 2:**
Uninstalling and reinstalling the app also helps, but that's another way of saying "Clear data" from `Settings > Apps` in this case, and it does not help you understand exactly what the issue is.

Comment: thanks its work... please help me more if i am creating two or three tables more in this database class so it is must to increase version of database from 2 to 3???

Comment: means if I'm alter my tables then i need to change the version of database every time....

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding 3rd table later, then you need to either uninstall your app and reinstall again or you have to increase your database version.

Comment: thanks its work... please help me more if i am creating two or three tables more in this database class so it is must to increse version of database from 2 to 3???

Comment: if you have published your 1st version of app in market and you have added another table in the 2nd version of your app, then you have to increase the database version so that onUpgrade method will get called and your database is refreshed automatically for your app users. If app is not published then you can uninstall the older version and run your app.

Comment: ok mean if i'm not publish my app now then i just uninstall this and this will work properly @Arun Kumar thank you :)